# deleting rows from sql through jsp

Tags: jsp

I developed a small web page which allows a user to register as a user and login. I have a admin login too wherein the admin can see all the users in the database and is able to delete or edit a user. So, I created two jsps one which is redirected when admin logs in and the other when he clicks delete. But due to some reason I am not getting directed to **delete** page from admin page.

admin.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" import="com.javadbproject.util.DBConnectionManager" import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
         pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
        <title>Home Page</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/loginstyle.css'/>"> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;


            Connection con = (Connection) getServletContext().getAttribute("DBConnection");
            ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from Users");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
        %>
        <table><tr><td>NAME : <%=rs.getString(1)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>EMAIL :<%=rs.getString(2)%></td></tr>

            <tr><td><a href = "delete.jsp">Delete</a></td></tr>
        </table>

        <%
            }
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        %>
        <form action="Logout" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Logout" >

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

delete.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" import="com.javadbproject.util.DBConnectionManager"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
         pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Delete Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Connection con = (Connection) getServletContext().getAttribute("DBConnection");
            String name = rs.getString(1);
            ps = con.prepareStatement("delete from Users where email=?");
            ps.setString(1, name);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am new to web programming so can someone let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just to let you know, generally in my experience placing Java code in your JSP is bad practice. I use to do this also in the beginning of my Java career and it leads to headaches for maintenance. If you are interested, review other design patterns such as MVC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass a value to delete.jsp (i.e. delete.jsp?email=test@gmail.com) in admin.jsp and then in delete.jsp obtain this value using request.getParameter("email").

I don't have a way to test this, but you might also need to URL encode the email value, otherwise it might break your web application.

Comment: Do I need to modify my query too in delete.jsp?  ps = con.prepareStatement("delete  from Users where email=?");

Comment: I'd modify this line:
String name = rs.getString(1);
to
String name = request.getParameter("email");

Comment: You have hardcoded to delete a specific email but how to get that dynamically but when I keep it like this                           <tr><td><a href = "delete.jsp?email=EMAIL">Delete</a></td></tr>              it goes to a webpage http://localhost:8085/JavaDBProject/delete.jsp?name=EMAIL

Comment: <table><tr><td>NAME : <%=rs.getString(1)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>EMAIL :<%=rs.getString(2)%></td></tr>

            <tr><td><a href = "delete.jsp?email=<%=rs.getString(2)%>">Delete</a></td></tr>
        </table>

Comment: Tried with your suggestions but I am running into 500 error. rechecked to see if there's any issue with db(it's fine)..web page link is http://localhost:8085/JavaDBProject/delete.jsp?name=Sa                  delete.jsp [link](http://pastebin.com/hCM2V7X6) admin.jsp [link](http://pastebin.com/Jzi25WvZ)

Comment: You still need to have ps.setString(1, name); so uncomment that and try it again otherwise your database is expecting a value and not getting one, which is probably throwing the stacktrace.

Comment: You were right, I tried to run in the debug mode. Now I see that in my delete statement the user name is passed but I am bit doubtful on result set object. It says executeQuery is referenced on null object(while in debug mode) Line 22 of admin.jsp.

Comment: I still am stuck up here. Any suggestions?